# I have issues in powershell script which will filter files of last 24 to 25 hrs and zip all those fines and ready for backup upload?

Tags: powershell, scripting

```
$source = "C:\folder\*.*"
$destination = "C:\folder3\test.zip"
$results = (Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *.* | ? {
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) 
}  
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($results, $destination)
```

Now i need to select last modified files and zip either by compress or 7zip any help ?

Answer (score 0):

To zip files via Powershell, I usually install 7-zip on the system and then include this function in the script:

```
#7-ZIP FILE FUNCTION (must install 7-zip on system)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
function ZipFile7 ([string] $pZipFile, [string] $pFiles) { 
    $7zipExe = "$($env:programfiles)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    $7zArgs = @("a", "-tzip", $pZipFile, $pFiles, "-r")
    & $7zipExe $7zArgs    
} 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`$pZipFile` is the full path of the file you wish to create, and `$pFiles` is the path to the files you wish to zip (can include wildcards like `C:\*.txt`).

Comment: 7zip is not working for my condition for take all files of last 25hrs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = "C:\folder\*.*"
$destination = "C:\folder3\test.zip"
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | Select -ExpandProperty "FullName"
set-content $destination ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
$Shell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
$ZipFile = $Shell.Namespace($destination)
$Results | ForEach {
    $Count = $ZipFile.Items().Count
    $ZipFile.CopyHere($_)
    While ($ZipFile.Items().Count -eq $Count) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200} # Wait till the file is zipped
}
```

Note: you might want to improve the while/wait statement (e.g. set a timeout) as it might hang if anything goes wrong with copying the file to the zip folder.

Comment: Thanks IRon worked like charm same will be uploading to s3 all my bak files

Comment: Ron i have an issue its not compressing .trm files and it says file do not have permissions any help ?

Comment: TRM files are probably already compressed and/or encrypted, meaning that they probably can't be compressed further (any prove that you can compress them in any other application, e.g. 7Zip?).

Comment: The permission error is likely related to the note I wrote in the answer: the `CopyHere` method is asynchronous yet you can not copy asynchronously copy files to a container. meaning that you have to wait until the previous file is compressed. e.g. is the $ZipFile still open?